# MySQL join inside subquery

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this:

```
# tab1 = Company
# tab2 = Forms
# tab3 = Filled forms from each company enabled to it.

# Search Companies with pending/empty Forms.
# Company #1 has 3 forms, all filled, not will be listed;
# Company #2 has form 2 and 3, only form 2 is filled, so it will be listed;
# Company #3 has not form filled, so it will be listed;

SELECT company.*
FROM tab1 as company

WHERE (
  SELECT TRUE
  FROM tab2 AS forms

  # Join compatible company forms results/fills.
  # Itll join with company.id (that here not exists) and the forms.id (that exists)
  LEFT JOIN tab3 AS fills ON
    fills.id_tab1 = company.id AND
    fills.id_tab2 = forms.id

  # Itll filter forms that company have.
  # And will accept ONLY if none result is found, what mean "pending fill" on company.
  # I need just that.
  WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET(forms.id, company.id_forms) AND
    fills.id IS NULL
)
```

And I get **Unknown column `tab1.id`**.
How to solve it?

I need have access to `tab1` columns inside of INNER of SUBQUERY.

**Update #1** -
**Live sample**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20aa5/3

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0):

try this code, the logic is the same

```
 SELECT tab1.* from tab1
        inner join tab3 ON  tab3.id_tab1 = tab1.id
    WHERE .....
```

Comment: Instead of just saying "try this", explain how it solves the problem (if it even does, which I'm thinking it doesn't).

Comment: I just doing my best to solve the problem, if it will not work @David Rodrigues will try something else. If you see his original code the tab.2 not related at all to the logic, it's just select true on tab2 if tab1.id=tab3.id so it's redundant.